# How to make a variable available to all classes in XNA/monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a couple of variables in my XNA/Monogame Tower Defense that I need to pass between classes. Unfortunately many of them are auto-generated so I can't just reference them in. Is there anything like a global variable that I can use? Again this is in Monogame(XNA) / C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a static class where you will store all your global variables and it will be accessible from all your classes.

```
public static class MyGlobals
{
    public static int LevelNumber { get; set; }
    public static string CurrentScore { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and access it from anywhere by

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        MyGlobals.LevelNumber = ...
        string score = MyGlobals.CurrentScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question but I feel very conflicted about it because it can lead to some very bad habits if you're not careful. Global static state is one of those things that will come back to bite you sooner or later. Consider what happens if you want to introduce multiple threads, unit testing, re-usability or many other reasons. If you are must go down this path at least read up on the risks first and consider how to can possibly use some form of dependency injection if possible. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'm more concerned about serialization when you want to be able to save and load a game. I would not bother with re-usability and unit testing, though. He's making a game. As for concurrent environment, one have to always pay attention.

Comment: Sure, create a singleton. But it still boils down to these problems. You can also leverage some kind of app settings or so, but it would basically mean to keep this settings in a file, which is not a bad idea until you need to access them to often. A static class is the smallest evil I guess.

Comment: If you can't use constructor injection the next best thing is property injection. There's also other things to consider.. factory pattern, service locator. We really need to know more details about your situation.

Comment: Well my situation is that I need to pass over just a couple of variables over to my main class. I'm curious though what is property injection (beginner programmer)? I think I will just use a static class though because I just have a few variables I need to pass over.

Comment: an OOP solution is an alternative. there should be some top level class that has an instance of your settings class as a member.